# Loop counter in D language

Tags: loops, d

In this tutorial (http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/foreach_opapply.html), it is commented that `If foreach support is provided by range member functions, then a loop counter can be achieved simply by enumerate from the std.range module:` with an example.

```
import std.range;

// ...

foreach (i, element; NumberRange(42, 47).enumerate) {
    writefln("%s: %s", i, element);
}
```

I tried to use this example to check the `enumerate`, but I got error `Error: no property 'enumerate' for type 'NumberRange'`. What might be wrong?

```
import std.stdio;
import std.range;

void main()
{
    foreach (i, element; iota(42, 47).enumerate) {
        writefln("%s: %s", i, element);
    }
}
```

Comment: In [the documentation](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html) I see the `retro` mutator also used in that tutorial, but none named `enumerate`.  But another version marked prerelease [does have it](http://dlang.org/phobos-prerelease/std_range.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumerate` was added after 2.066 was released. It will be available in 2.067.

BTW, you may or may not be aware of it, but you can use `std.range.iota` instead of NumberRange.